# How do I use Jquery's load function in this js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

The code for the website I'm currently working on (posted below) is currently not functional. When it was all contained in only the index.html file (meaning all of my code, other libraries / plugins were referenced correctly and stored elsewhere of course), everything worked perfectly. I'm trying to change the structure of the site to function using JQuery's load function, however, so I can swap the #content-display div out for different information when someone clicks a link, allowing me to add JQuery animations for a seamless experience.

There may be an easier way to accomplish this effect, but I'd like to learn what's going wrong with the load function now so that I can use it effectively for projects in the future.

I'm including all of the relevant code below. I'd like to get the slideshow operational again and then from there I should be able to fix the other functions myself. The slideshow uses the plugin MaxImage2.

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta content="Personal Portfolio of Christopher Willingham" name=
"description">
<meta content="" name="author">

<title>CWPhotography</title>
<link href="img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link charset="utf-8" href="css/jquery.maximage.css?v=1.2" media="screen"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <a href="#" id="link-slideshow">christopher willingham photography</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="col-md-5 alignright" id="navlist">
                <li>
                    <a id="link-portfolio">portfolio</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a id="link-about">about</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a id="link-contact">contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" id="content-display"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/jquery.maximage.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/modules/jfunc.js">
    (function(){
            Main.init();
            Main.bindUI();
        }());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

jfunc.js (located under js/modules/jfunc, relative to the index):

```
var Main = {

init: function() {

    $('#content-display').load("slideshow.html");


    $('#maximage').maximage({
        cycleOptions: {
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 800,
            timeout: 7200,
        },
        onFirstImageLoaded: function() {
            jQuery('#cycle-loader').hide();
            jQuery('#maximage').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });

},

bindUI: function() {

    $('#link-portfolio').click(function() {
        $('#content-display').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content-display').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'portfolio.html',
            success: function() {
                $.get('portfolio.html', function(page) {
                    $('#content-display').html(page);
                });
            }
        });
        $('#content-display').fadeIn('fast');
    });

    $('#link-about').click(function() {
        $('#content-display').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content-display').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'about.html',
            success: function() {
                $.get('about.html', function(page) {
                    $('#content-display').html(page);
                });
            }
        });
        $('#content-display').fadeIn('fast');
    });

    $('#link-contact').click(function() {
        $('#content-display').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content-display').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'contact.html',
            success: function() {
                $.get('contact.html', function(page) {
                    $('#content-display').html(page);
                });
            }
        });
        $('#content-display').fadeIn('fast');
    });

    $('#link-slideshow').click(function() {
        $('#content-display').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content-display').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'slideshow.html',
            success: function() {
                $.get('slideshow.html', function(page) {
                    $('#content-display').html(page);
                });
            }
        });
        $('#content-display').fadeIn('fast');
    });
}

};
```

slideshow.html (stored in the same folder as index.html):

```
<html lang="en">

<div id="maximage" class="mc-cycle transitDiv" >
    <div class="first-item">
        <img src="img/slideshow/slide1.jpg" alt="" width="2048" height="1152" />
    </div>
    <img src="img/slideshow/slide2.jpg" alt="" width="2048" height="1152" />
    <img src="img/slideshow/slide3.jpg" alt="" width="2048" height="1152" />
    <img src="img/slideshow/slide4.jpg" alt="" width="2048" height="1152" />
</div>

</html>
```

Once again, just to reiterate, I wasn't having any issues until I tried separating the code into different objects and calling the .load function from the js file, so I'm assuming the issue is with my pathing or in the syntax I use to call the functions, but I've been trying everything I can think of and I'm at wit's end now. Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: why are you calling `$.get` inside `$.ajax` success callback? You can directly use `$.get` :)

Comment: Try `<script src="js/modules/jfunc.js"></script>` and then `<script>function(){Main.init();Main.bindUI();}());</script>`

Comment: Remove the `<html>` and `</html>` from slideshow.html.  You just want a piece of regular HTML.

Comment: Firebug gives me:

"SyntaxError: function statement requires a name"

Whenever I try to call the script like that. I was using $.get inside the success callback simply because I was mimicking how the jquery documentation does it, but now I'm focused on using $.load if that's possible. If I can get the slideshow working, I'll just go through and modify the other functions to match.

Comment: @jfriend00 I should mention that if I try to use the $.load function by including it inside index.html, I can retrieve the slideshow.html content just fine, so I don't think there's anything wrong with that. It's when I call the $.load function through the js var that it stops working.

Regardless, I tried removing the html tags and it changed nothing.

Comment: @Alebon- did you read my answer?  That is certainly keeping your code from working.  I don't know if it's the only issue or not, but it IS an issue.  Also, the `<html>` and `</html>` tags should NOT be there in slideshow.html.  You don't insert those into the middle of a page which is what you are trying to do.  It may not cause a problem, but it is wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I hadn't read your answer when I commented, but your answer helped me out so much. I'll remove the <html> tags gladly, since you're clearly more experienced here haha. I simply misunderstood how load worked. I thought it would take everything in between those tags, rather than everything saved after <!doctype>. Thanks for the advice.

I left a comment on your answer too, if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `<script>` tag with both a `.src` property and script between the tags.  You must use two separate `<script>` tags for that.

Change this:

```
<script src="js/modules/jfunc.js">
    (function(){
            Main.init();
            Main.bindUI();
        }());
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="js/modules/jfunc.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
            Main.init();
            Main.bindUI();
        }());
</script>
```

P.S. there appears to be no reason for the IIFE either.  You're just making two function calls.  No reason to wrap another function around that.

Comment: Thank you so much, man! That gets me SO much further. The MaxImage script still doesn't seem to function when the slideshow content (the #content-display div) is loaded rather than included with index.html. Do you have any idea why that is?

Also I would love to +1 this but my account is new and it won't allow me.

Comment: @Alebon - it's probably a load order problem.  You can't apply jQuery operations to the slideshow DOM elements until AFTER the `.load()` operation has completed.  You would have to pass a callback into `.load()` and initialize the slideshow in that callback.

Comment: So, just to make sure I'm reading this right, it's like a success callback for Ajax? I can check jquery documentation to make sure I get the syntax right, too.

And thanks so much for explaining things out like that, I'm still in the process of learning javascript, but the terminology makes sense to me from all my C++ classes, which has helped a lot. You've been the man tonight!

Comment: @Alebon - yes, it work similarly to a success handler for an Ajax call and that's because `.load()` is actually an ajax call internally.  FYI, even though you can't upvote yet, you can select a best answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's why I had to start working in apache to test it! I'm so glad I dug through stack overflow to read up on how ajax works and how it doesn't handle file protocols through browser well, or else that would just be another layer of complications.

I checked your answer, thanks again!